# Firebase - restrict API key for web application

Tags: firebase

I just got a mail from the Firebase support that my current API key restrictions for the Firebase API key lead to malfunctions for the Firebase Installation API. Since, I have a web application and not an iOS or an Android app, I´m assuming that this is not a real issue for me at the moment.

However, this got me wondering if I enabled all necessary HTTP referrers (websites) in the Google Cloud Platform to ensure a working environment for my web application. Let´s say my domain is called `www.domain.com` and my Firebase project is called `projectx`. I currently have these two entries in the HTTP referrers for the Application restrictions:

- [www.domain.com/](http://www.domain.com/)*
- projectx.firebaseapp.com/*

Is there anything else I should enable? Because I saw that Firebase also enables multiple domains such as `projectx.web.app` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple: you need to enable the domains that your app uses.

The two domains you have are the defaults for cases where you have a common domain:

- [www.yourdomain.com/](http://www.yourdomain.com/)* is the custom domain that you typically share out with people.
- projectx.firebaseapp.com is the default domain generated by Firebase, and is typically also used in sign-in screens (although you *can* change this).

You may also want to add:

- projectx.web.app, which is a newer default domain that Firebase creates. But this is not required, so only add it if you expect to hand it out to folks.
- localhost, which is handy for local testing

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the information I needed. Also +1 for adding the hint that it is possible to customize the default sign-in domain.